Sums of a square and two cubes
I recently came across this article published in 1995 that discusses integers that can be expressed in the form $x^2 + y^3 + z^3$, where $x$, $y$, and $z$ are integers, possibly negative.
The article focuses on the following two identities :
$$9t=(3t+3)^2+(t-1)^3-(t+2)^3\,,$$
and
$$3t+1=(3t+8)^2+(t+1)^3-(t+4)^3\,.$$
At the time, it was an open question whether any integer could be decomposed.
Do you know if there have been any developments since that time ?
I managed to find the following identities (possibly already known !):
$$(6t)^2+(t-6)^3-(t+6)^3=-432\;\;\;(0)\,,$$
$$(4t^3+12t+12)^2-(2t^2-2t)^3-(2t^2+2t+4)^3=192t+80\;\;\;(1)\,,$$
$$(4t^3)^2-(2t^2-2t-2)^3-(2t^2+2t-2)^3=16\;\;\;(2)\,.$$
$(1)$ is "interesting" because  $80\equiv2\;(\text{mod}\,3)$.
This doesn't move the problem forward much...

I don't dare use your decomposition $37^3+11^3=228^2$, because when I used the decomposition $1^3+2^3=3^2$, I didn't get anything new : the simplest identity I've obtained is $(3t^3-9t^2+81t+81)^2-(t+3)^6-(2t^2-6t+18)^3=9(1944t)$.

@Will Jagy Sorry, I was writing the reply to your comment when you deleted it.

uvdose, thank you for your comments. You are certainly correct to worry about new identities giving nothing more than the identities you already know.

@uvdose: Your remark on  $80\equiv2;(\text{mod},3)$ is in fact useful because it is near from the general case  $n\equiv {-1}\pmod 3$ wich remains for solving the general problem. In other words, which remainds to do is the case $3t-1$ in the LHS.

I made microscopic progress this morning by finding the identity $(4t^3+48t+96)^2-(2t^2+4t+16)^3-(2t^2-4t)^3=6144t+5120$, which is "new" because $6144t+5120=192(32t+26)+128$.

Any parametrization that is linear in $x$, $y$ and $z$ that results in a linear expression will have its constant term congruent to $1$ mod $3$.

Just one ingredient:  one family of $x^3 + y^3 = z^2$ came out  $u = p^2 + q^2, \; \; $ $v = p^2 - q^2, \; \; $   then $x =  u^2 +2uv - 2 v^2 $    and $y = 2 u^2 - 2 uv - v^2 $
Seems possible all such parametrizations for $x^3 + y^3 = z^2$ are known, this is just one:
$$x =  p^4 + 6q^2p^2 - 3q^4  $$
and
$$ y = -p^4 + 6q^2p^2 + 3q^4 $$
give
$$  x^3 + y^3 = 36 p^2q^2 (p^4 + q^4)^2 $$

Determining the integers that are representable by the form $F(x,y,z)=x^3+y^3+z^2$ is entirely different problem from finding the solutions of the diophantine $x^3+y^3=z^2$. By the way, the equation $x^3+y^3=2z^2$ it is known has been completely solved but $x^3+y^3=z^2$ has been solved with several parameterizations but not completely. Regards.
